# Google App Script - onFormSubmit - copyTo cell in spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy-paste

I have a script that copies a certain cell when a new form is submitted, (which contains a drop down list, on sheet "Validation") and pastes it into the first blank cell in column A on the sheet "Internal Recruitment Requests".

The code is not copying into the right cell.

Below is the current script, which doesn't work.

I am running it with `onEdit` at the moment for testing purposes.

```
function onEdit() { 

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Validation');
    var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Internal Recruitment Requests');
    var lastEmptyOnColumnA = sheet2.getRange("A1:A" +    sheet2.getLastRow()).getValues().join(",").replace(/,,/g, '').split(",").length;
    var DVcopyFrom = sheet1.getRange("A4");
    var DVcopyTo = sheet2.getRange('A' + lastEmptyOnColumnA);

    sheet1.getRange(DVcopyFrom).copyToRange(sheet2.getRange(DVcopyTo),  {contentsOnly:false});

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bingo, all sorted. used the below script which was a tiny tweak on what you had given me. thanks for the help :)

```js
function onEdit() { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Validation');
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Internal Recruitment Requests');

  var lastRowSheet2 = sheet2.getLastRow();
  var cellRefLastRowSheet2 = "A1:A" + lastRowSheet2.toString();
  var cellRefLastRowSheet2Empty = "A" + lastRowSheet2.toString();
  var lastEmptyOnColumn_A_Sheet2 = sheet2.getRange(cellRefLastRowSheet2);

  var DVcopyFromValue = sheet1.getRange("A4");

  var contentOfLastCell = sheet2.getRange(cellRefLastRowSheet2Empty).getValue();

  if (contentOfLastCell === "") 
  {
    DVcopyFromValue.copyTo(sheet2.getRange(cellRefLastRowSheet2Empty));
  }
}
```